# Is $\{ a_{m}(n) | a_{m}(n)$ with all even digits$\}$ finite set for all $m$?

Tags: number-theory

For $m \ge 1$, define $a_{m}(n)$ as the following,

> $a_{m}(1) = m$,
>
> $a_{m}(n + 1) = 2  a_{m}(n).$

Consider the set $X_m = \{ a_{m}(n) | a_{m}(n)$ with all even digits$\}$.

For example,

$X_1 = X_2 = \{ 2, 4, 8, 64, \cdots \}$,

$X_3 = X_6 = \{ 6, 24, \cdots \}$,

$X_4 = \{ 4, 8, 64, \cdots \}$,

$X_5 = \{ 20, 40, 80, 640, \cdots \}$,

$X_7 = \{ 28, 224, \cdots \}$.

Is $X_m$ finite set for all $m$?

P.S.

This([Is 2048 the highest power of 2 with all even digits (base ten)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116026/is-2048-the-highest-power-of-2-with-all-even-digits-base-ten?rq=1)) is in the case of $m = 2$.

Comment: Do you even know any $m$ for sure where $X_m$ is finite?

Comment: Even for m = 2, it is difficult problem. See https://oeis.org/A068994.

Comment: So a simpler(?) preliminary question might be: Is there any $m$ for which it is known whether $X_m$ is finite or infinite?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I think it isn't known whether $X_{m}$ is finite or infinite for any $m$.