# Find all natural numbers of the form $2^n$ whose all digits are even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Find all natural numbers of the form $2^n$ whose all digits are even. For example: $2, 4, 8, 64, 2048$ (I believe they are the only such numbers).

For $n \geq 11$, so far, I can prove that the last digit of such number must be $4$ or $8$. Moreover, the last $2$ digits must be $24,64,08,48$ or $88$. Then I don't know how to procede next. I also found that such number must be of the form $2^{4k+2}$ or $2^{4k+3}$, for $k \geq 3$.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A068994 -- it looks like it's an open problem.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Thanks! (Sadly) this is what I'm looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116026/is-2048-the-highest-power-of-2-with-all-even-digits-base-ten

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: yes, you are right.