# Distribution of digits in powers of 2

Tags: number-theory

Writing down a couple of powers of two, I saw that

$$2^{23} = 8388608$$

which seemed to contain an abnormally high amount of 8's. I then thought what if by choosing appropriate values of $k$ and $n$, I can get $D(k,n)$ as close to $1$ as I liked, where $D(k,n)$ is the percentage of digits in $2^n$ that are equal to $k$. For example,

$$D(8,23) = \frac{4}{7}$$

because there are $4$ instances of the digit $8$ in the number $2^{23}$ in base 10 (which has 7 digits). Of course, we have some trivial solutions like

$$D(4,2) = 1$$

because 2 squared is 4, but I'm interested in $n > 3$. After some computer simulation, however, it seems like this is probably definitely not the case, though I have no idea how to prove it either way.

(A similar conjecture that might be true is if by choosing an appropriate value of $n$, I can get $E(k,n)$ as close to $0.1$ as I like, where $E(k,n)$ is defined by:

$$E(k,n) = \text{minimum } D(k,n) \text{ achievable by varying k and keeping n constant}$$

---

I tried to approach this by looking at the 'period' of each digit. For instance, the last digit cycles with period $4$, (it goes 2, 4, 8, 6 then back to 2), and the second last digit cycles with period $20$, then period $100$, then period $500$, though a) I don't know how to explain the pattern in this cycling (has it got anything to do with the fact we are using base 10 and 10 = 2 times 5?) and b) I've got no idea how to use this fact to prove either conjecture

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/116026/140607) is highly relevant.

Comment: I think we should ask to Gabriele Dalla Torre that investigated similar problems: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/ic/2010.html

Comment: To explain the last digits cycling, for three digits you need them to be divisible by $8$.  There are $125$ three digit combinations that are divisible by $8$, but the $25$ ending in $0$ are not allowed.  This doesn't prove that we cycle through them all, but it gives a maximum which is achieved.