# Number of zeros in the decimal representation of $2^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In the binary representation of $2^n$ I know there are $n-1$ zeros. Yet I'm not sure how can I find the function to calculate the number of zeros in the decimal representation. It seems to be possible using a function translating from binary to decimal but I can't manage to put the things together. Would be happy for any help.

Comment: I do not think that such a function exists (in the sense of a formula). You simply have to count the zeros in general.

Comment: This just OEIS [A027870](https://oeis.org/A027870). There appears to be no closed form.

Comment: If so, theoretically, do you mean it is unknown and very hard to answer? Or it can be proved that there is no function (that can be expressed as a formula, say, using the symbols of addition, multiplication and power)?

Comment: Studying representations of powers in various bases is a hard problem, see e.g. problems mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118615/127263). It dare to guess it's completely open whether there always is at least a single zero in the decimal expansion of $2^n$ for large enough $n$ (though we would expect, on average, the digits to be more or less evenly distributed, so 1/10 of the digits "should" be zeros). Edit: Seems my guess was right, [relevant OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007377)