# infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $3^n$ has all digits non-zero

Tags: number-theory

Are there infinitely many $$n\in\mathbb N$$ such that $3^n$ has all digits non-zero?

Comment: No.  Of  course not.  But I cannot prove this (correct) answer.

Comment: Simple heuristic arguments point to "no", but I think this problem is unsolved.  See also the "86 conjecture" http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/status-of-a-conjecture-about-powers-of-2

Comment: Hendrik Lenstra says that recreational number theory is "that branch of Number Theory which is too difficult for serious study." I think you have a good example of that here.

Answer (score 1):

The known powers of 3 with no zeros are tabulated [here](http://oeis.org/A030700). There are 22 of them, the largest being $3^{68}$. There is a link there to a page where it is claimed that the search of numbers $3^k$ has gone out to $k=10^8$ without finding any more. So I think GEdgar has it about right in his comment.