# Call a number "holy" if it contains no $666$ in its decimal expansion. Are there infinitely many holy powers of $2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

We call a number "holy" if it contains no $666$ in its decimal expansion, and "unholy" otherwise. For instance, $12366621$ and $666609$ are unholy, while $7777$ and $66166266366$ are holy.

> **Question**: Is the set $$\{2^n \ | \ n \in \mathbb N, 2^n \text{ is holy}\}$$ infinite?

Of course, tons of similar questions can be asked by changing the number $666$, the base $2$, and the base for extension (we asked for decimal, so the default was $10$). I do not feel that I am the first one asking this, and I appreciate it if someone gives me references if applicable.

But my thought is the following:

> **Conjecture**: No.

I will share my reasoning at the end of the post, but let us first see some facts:

**Smallest unholy instances**:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{157} &= 182687704\color{magenta}{666}362864775460604089535377456991567872\\
2^{192} &= 6277101735386680763835789423207\color{magenta}{666}416102355444464034512896
\end{aligned}
$$

Then, we witnessed a cluster of unholy powers: $2^{218}, 2^{220}, 2^{222}, 2^{224}, 2^{226}$, and then kept holy for a while, until we hit the unholy $2^{243}$.

**Largest holy instances**: I did not throw in a lot of CPU time to pursue holy numbers, nor did I try hard enough to optimize my programs, but among the $3715$ holy powers of $2$, the largest of them are
$$2^{25357}, 2^{25896}, 2^{26051}, 2^{26667}, 2^{29784}.$$

I tested up to around $2^{110000}$, but that is all I got. It probably will be reasonable for an average computer to test up to say $2^{10^6}$ or $2^{10^7}$, but I will be surprised to see a new holy number.

**Statistics**: For an integer $n$, let $H(n)$ be the number of holy powers of $2$ up to $2^n$.

```
n      | H(n)     || n      | H(n)     || n      | H(n)
 1000  |  875     || 11000  | 3567     || 21000  | 3700
 2000  | 1560     || 12000  | 3602     || 22000  | 3703
 3000  | 2059     || 13000  | 3621     || 23000  | 3705
 4000  | 2442     || 14000  | 3645     || 24000  | 3707
 5000  | 2747     || 15000  | 3655     || 25000  | 3709
 6000  | 2984     || 16000  | 3670     || 26000  | 3712
 7000  | 3171     || 17000  | 3682     || 27000  | 3714
 8000  | 3332     || 18000  | 3689     || 28000  | 3714
 9000  | 3440     || 19000  | 3693     || 29000  | 3714
10000  | 3514     || 20000  | 3695     || 30000  | 3715
```

A plot of this:
[image]

**The heuristics of the conjecture**:

This is definitely not close to a proof at all, and I still hope if rigorous arguments exists:

The idea is that we want to estimate, for an integer $n$, the probability $P(n)$ that $2^n$ is holy, and then compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n)$.

We know that $2^n$ has $O(n\ln 2)$ decimal digits, so there are $O(n\ln 2)$ groups of three. For each group there is a $1-10^{-3}$ chance to be not $666$, so very roughly
$$
P(n) = (1-10^{-3})^{n\ln 2} \approx e^{-10^{-3}\ n\ln 2}.
$$

And note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n) \approx \int_{n=0}^\infty e^{-10^{-3}\ x\ln 2} dx < \infty.
$$

The red "estimation line" in the figure above follows from this integral.

Of course, one can easily argue the properness of the heuristic above:

- The distribution of the digits close to the left are not uniform; they are  affected by the growth of logarithmic functions.
- The distribution of the digits close to the right are not uniform; they are affected by the pattern of $2^n \pmod{10^k}$.
- $P(n)$ and $P(n+i)$ are not independent, partially because of the awful choice of the number $666$: $6\cdots 6 \times 2^2 = 26\cdots 64$.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't help, but a cute application of Dirichlet denseness theorem shows that there are infinitely many powers of 2 starting with the digits 666.... They are unholly but very rare.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! At least it shows that unholy powers appears in density at least $\log_{10} 667/666$. Not sure how well we can push this number to somewhere close to $1$ by the similar approach.

Comment: Your conjecture is indeed a known open problem, and in fact we expect that there is some $N>0$ such that $666$ occurs among the digits of the decimal expansion of $2^n$, for every $n>N$ ! See http://blog.tanyakhovanova.com/2011/02/86-conjecture/, https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/11/23/digits-in-powers-of-2, OEIS A035064, A030706, A007377, A035062. $$ $$ Closely related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167607, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199682

Comment: [Here is a relevant open problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajT2d.png) by Fürstenberg, which apparently gives an approach to the above conjecture (even though I'm not sure to understand why), according to the page 189 of _Ten Lectures on the Interface between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis_ (reference given in John Cook's post linked above). See also problems 10.25 and 10.27 in Yann Bugeaud's _Distribution Modulo One and Diophantine Approximation_.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, [here is an excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVaHq.png) of Fürstenberg's paper explaining the relation between the two problems (Conjectures 2 and 2' in his paper). Reference: _Intersections of Cantor sets and transversality of semigroups_ in "Problems in Analysis. A Symposium in Honor of Salomon Bochner ".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not an answer, but only a few comments.

Your conjecture is indeed a known open problem, and in fact we expect that there is some $N>0$ such that $666$ occurs among the digits of the decimal expansion of $2^n$, for every $n>N$ ! Of course, one can replace $k=666$ by any positive integer $k$ (more accurately, any sequence of digits).

See also 
[this blog post](http://blog.tanyakhovanova.com/2011/02/86-conjecture/) (for the case $k=0$),
[Problem 24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulehg.png) in *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* by Richard Guy, 
[here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/11/23/digits-in-powers-of-2), 
or those OEIS sequences : [A035064](https://oeis.org/A035064), 
[A030706](https://oeis.org/A030706), 
[A007377](https://oeis.org/A007377), 
[A035062](https://oeis.org/A035062). 
These are closely related questions : 
[(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/status-of-a-conjecture-about-powers-of-2), 
[(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167607),
[(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199682).

[Here is a relevant open problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajT2d.png) by Fürstenberg, which apparently gives an approach to the above conjecture (even though I'm not sure to understand why), according to the page 189 of *Ten Lectures on the Interface between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis* (reference given in John Cook's post linked above). 
See also [problems 10.25 and 10.27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDiLJ.png) in Yann Bugeaud's *Distribution Modulo One and Diophantine Approximation*.
According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08053.pdf), Fürstenberg's conjecture is just "far out of reach" !
Similarly, in §6.6, p. 138 of Bugeaud's book, it is mentioned that "Erdős asked how often the ternary expansion of $2^n$ omits the digit $2$. It is likely that there are only finitely many such integers $n$ but the problem is still beyond reach"$^{[1]}$ !

For the sake of completeness, [here is an excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVaHq.png) of Fürstenberg's paper explaining the relation between the two problems (Conjectures 2 and 2' in his paper). Reference: *Intersections of Cantor sets and transversality of semigroups* in "Problems in Analysis. A Symposium in Honor of Salomon Bochner".

To sum up, we *expect* any given sequence of digits to occur in the decimal expansion of all but finitely many powers of $2$, but this is currently an unsolved problem which is out of reach!

---

$^{[1]}$ One of the best result known so far is given as exercise 6.4 in Bugeaud's book. Namely, if $N(X)$ denotes the number of positive integers $m \leq X$ such that $2^m$ has no "$2$" in its ternary expansion, then
$N(X) \leq 1.62 X^{\log(2) / \log (3)}$. The (intractable) conjecture is that $N(X)$ is bounded.